Hardware test for embedded device with multiple NICs
I am in the process of writing software to test Linux based embedded devices after manufacturing. Each of the devices has multiple physical network interfaces, all internally bridged to a Linux bridge br0.
Problem:

I need to find out if all of the NICs of the DUT are working properly (i.e. nothing went wrong during manufacturing).

The test setup is as follows:

All Ethernet NICs of the DUT (MAC addresses are known, STP deactivated, IPv4/IPv6 activated) are physically connected to separate ports (let's say 1-3) of a managed switch
The system running the test software (also Linux) is physically connected to the same switch (let's say on port 4).

What I did so far:

I made sure exactly one of the switch ports (1-3) was enabled (ifAdminStatus=up) via SNMP and then send simply pinged the DUT to see if the connected NIC is working and repeated the process for all switch ports/NICs. This, however, is somewhat slow as the switch needs ~3.5 seconds to (de-)activate a switch port and introduces additional delay until a ping is then successful. This adds up to ~15 seconds which I consider way to long.

Ideally, I'd like to activate all switch ports 1-3 simultaneously and do the test in parallel on layer 2 or 3.
Question:
What would be we the best way to design a simple and fast (!) test to find out if all NICs are working and simultanously avoiding all of the inherent problems (broadcast storms due to switching loops, ...)?

You might use iperf3 with the bind option to force it to use a given interface, see this question. On the server you can alias the nic with 3 ip addresses so you can run 3 servers simultaneously. Also, use ethtool -S to get statistics on errors, and check the negotation result etc.
